# arithmetic calculator coding always 0

Tags: php

Hello guys i am coding a calculator but the result i got is always 0 no matter what hare is my code :

```
<?php
function sortBySpeed($a, $b) {
    return $b['Speed'] - $a['Speed'];
}


if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    $ninjas = array( array( 
                      'Name' => "Main", 
                      'Damage' => $_POST["dmg1"],
                      'Damagerate' => $_POST["dmgrate1"],
                      'Damagegrow' => $_POST["dmggrow1"],
                      'Speed' => $_POST["speed1"],
                      'Fury' => 50
                    ),
                array( 
                      'Name' => $_POST["ninja2"], 
                      'Damage' => $_POST["dmg2"],
                      'Damagerate' => $_POST["dmgrate2"],
                      'Damagegrow' => $_POST["dmggrow2"],
                      'Speed' => $_POST["speed2"],
                      'Fury' => 50
                    ),
                array( 
                      'Name' => $_POST["ninja3"], 
                      'Damage' => $_POST["dmg3"],
                      'Damagerate'=> $_POST["dmgrate3"],
                      'Damagegrow' => $_POST["dmggrow3"],
                      'Speed' => $_POST["speed3"],
                      'Fury' => 50
                    ),
                array( 
                      'Name' => $_POST["ninja4"], 
                      'Damage' => $_POST["dmg4"],
                      'Damagerate' => $_POST["dmgrate4"],
                      'Damagegrow' => $_POST["dmggrow4"],
                      'Speed' => $_POST["speed4"],
                      'Fury' => 50
                    ),
                array( 
                      'Name' => $_POST["ninja5"], 
                      'Damage' => $_POST["dmg5"],
                      'Damagerate' => $_POST["dmgrate5"],
                      'Damagegrow' => $_POST["dmggrow5"],
                      'Speed' => $_POST["speed5"],
                      'Fury' => 50
                    )
             );


    $totaldmg = 0;
    $damagerate = 0;
    $damagegrow = 0;
    $furydmg = 0;

    usort($ninjas, 'sortBySpeed');  
    for($x = 0; $x < 6; $x++){
        for($a = 0; $a < 5; $a++){
            if($ninjas[$a]["Name"] == "Kabuto" && $x > 0){
                for($b = 0; $b < 5; $b++){
                    $ninjas[$b]["Fury"] +=25;
                }

                if($ninjas[$a]["Fury"] == 100){
                    $damagerate == $ninjas[$a]["Damage"]/100*$ninjas[$a]["Damagerate"];
                    $damagegrow == $damagerate/100*$ninjas[$a]["Damagegrow"];
                    $totaldmg += $damagegrow;
                    $ninjas[$a]["Fury"] == 0;
                }else if($ninjas[$a]["Fury"] > 100){
                    $damagerate == $ninjas[$a]["Damage"]/100*$ninjas[$a]["Damagerate"];
                    $damagegrow == $damagerate/100*$ninjas[$a]["Damagegrow"];
                    $furydmg == $damagegrow + ($damagegrow/100)*(($ninjas[$a]["Fury"]-100)/0.25);
                    $totaldmg += $damagegrow;
                    $ninjas[$a]["Fury"] == 0;
                }else{
                    $ninjas[$a]["Fury"] +=50;
                    $damagerate == $ninjas[$a]["Damage"]/100*$ninjas[$a]["Damagerate"];
                    $totaldmg += $damagerate;
                }

            }else{
                if($ninjas[$a]["Fury"] == 100){
                    $damagerate == $ninjas[$a]["Damage"]/100*$ninjas[$a]["Damagerate"];
                    $damagegrow == $damagerate/100*$ninjas[$a]["Damagegrow"];
                    $totaldmg += $damagegrow;
                    $ninjas[$a]["Fury"] == 0;
                }else if($ninjas[$a]["Fury"] > 100){
                    $damagerate == $ninjas[$a]["Damage"]/100*$ninjas[$a]["Damagerate"];
                    $damagegrow == $damagerate/100*$ninjas[$a]["Damagegrow"];
                    $furydmg == $damagegrow + ($damagegrow/100)*(($ninjas[$a]["Fury"]-100)/0.25);
                    $totaldmg += $damagegrow;
                    $ninjas[$a]["Fury"] == 0;
                }else{
                    $ninjas[$a]["Fury"] +=50;
                    $damagerate == $ninjas[$a]["Damage"]/100*$ninjas[$a]["Damagerate"];
                    $totaldmg += $damagerate;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    echo $totaldmg;

}

?>
```

so i made a form where user input values of all array data and then try to calculate total damage of all ninjas per 6 fights there is 5 ninjas so i made a for loop(6 fight) and then inside for loop(5 ninjas ) and make some calculation but i always got 0 , maybe someone knows where i made a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad should use = when giving a new meaning not ==